# Query to pull the value in the third row using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am developing a dashboard on Grafana and I am pulling across gas prices to display on the dashboard.

The table is called ‘gas_market_prices’ and it is regularly pulling in the latest prices. As outlined in red in the figure below, I need to continually pull the value in the third row of the ‘dqgm_6am_final_price’, ‘dqgm_10am_final_price’, dqgm_2pm_final_price’, ‘dqgm_6pm_final_price’ and ‘dqgm_10pm_final_price’ columns.

Table Layout

[image]

Below is the current query I am using to pull the data from ‘dwgm_2pm_final_price’, however, it is only pulling the most recent not null value (in this case 5.0599 where it should pull the value null). How can I edit the query so that it always pulls the value in the third row, regardless of it is null or an actual numerical value.

```
SELECT gas_date as 'time', dwgm_2pm_final_price
from gas_market_prices 
where dwgm_2pm_final_price is not null
order by gas_date desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to use limit with offset here:

```sql
SELECT gas_date AS time, dwgm_2pm_final_price
FROM gas_market_prices 
WHERE dwgm_2pm_final_price IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY gas_date DESC LIMIT 2, 1;
```